# Show that if $S=\text{span}\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ then $AS = \text{span}\{Ax_1,...,A_k\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A \in \mathbb{C^{n\times n}},\quad S$ a subspace of $\mathbb{C^n}\quad$  and  $AS = \{Ax | x\in S\}$

Show that if $S=\text{span}\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ then $AS = \text{span}\{Ax_1,...,Ax_k\}$

My try: Let $S=\text{span}\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ then $AS=\{Ax | x \in \text{span}(x_1,...,x_k)\}$. We also know that $AS$ is a subspace of $ \mathbb{C^n}$. Then $AS = \text{span}\{Ax_1,...,Ax_k\}$

I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: Do you really mean $A \in {\mathbb C}^n$, or is it supposed to be an $n \times n$  matrix?

Comment: To show 2 sets are equal it is best to show that one is contained in other and vice-versa. So here try showing $AS \subseteq span\{Ax_1,...,Ax_k\}$ and reverse.

Comment: I guess OP means $\Bbb{C}^n$ as $\Bbb{F}^n$??

Comment: Writing $A \in {\mathbb C}^{n \times n}$ doesn't mean that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, just that it's a very long vector. But, anyway, assuming $A$ is supposed to be a matrix, you hardly give an argument. You have expanded the definition of $AS$ -- that's the first step -- but at some point you'll have to use the definition of $\text{span}$ as well and the fact that multiplication with $A$ is linear. Showing both inclusions, as Rick suggests, is then the way to go.

Comment: (Strictly speaking, the claim that $AS$ is a subspace used the fact that multiplication by $A$ is linear already).